# How do I validate username and password using database table in the static main?

Tags: c#, authentication, validation, asp.net-web-api

I am currently attempting to implement authentication in an ASP.NET Web API. To achieve this, I am utilizing idunno.Authentication.Basic. My main objective is to compare the authorized user's table against the user input. Unfortunately, I have encountered an issue where I am unable to instantiate the UserContext class within the static main

I tried passing the Configure options, but it gave me the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<minimalAPI.models.UserContext>'

Here is the code in the program.cs file:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MinimalAPIDatabase")));//registers the UserContext class in the service container with a database connection string. This allows the application to use the UserContext instance to access and manipulate data from the database.

            


            //uses idunno.Authentication.Basic
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddBasic(options =>
                {
                    options.Realm = "Basic Authentication";
                    options.Events = new BasicAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnValidateCredentials = async context =>
                        {


                            string username = context.Username;
                            string password = context.Password;

                            var options = builder.Services.ConfigureOptions(null);
                            
                            UserContext _userContext = new UserContext(options);

                            AuthUser? user = await _userContext.AuthUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == username && u.Password == password);

                            if (user != null)

                                if (user != null)
                                {
                                    var claims = new[]
                                    {
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.Username, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Username, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                                                    };

                                    context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                                    context.Success();
                                }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

Here is the UserContext class:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
    {       
        public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : base(options)
        {
          
        }


        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AuthUser> AuthUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do not store passwords in a database. Even for "educational purposes". It's training very very bad behavior. There is much more to be learned if you dive into Auth providers instead of performing highly insecure authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you having error in this line

```
var options = builder.Services.ConfigureOptions(null);
```

instead you should write these lines

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MinimalAPIDatabase"));
var options = optionsBuilder.options;
```